# Test if Solr is running and restart

Tags: bash, solr

I have an script that restarts Solr which I run from cron.:

```
./restartsolr.sh 
systemctl stop solr
systemctl start solr
```

How can I add a test to only stop & start solr if solr status is inactive.

Running service solr status when stopped gives:

```
 solr.service - LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/solr; generated)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2022-07-08 16:52:14 UTC; 1min 55s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 16432 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/solr start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 16671 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/solr stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

So using bash can I write something like

```
solr_status  = service solr status
if solrstatus.include "dead"
    systemctl stop solr
    systemctl start solr
end
```

What would the syntax be in bash for that? Is this the best way / an ok way to monitor solr ?

Comment: Would `systemctl is-active solr || systemclt start solr` suffice? I would avoid trying to parse the output of `status` if possible.

Comment: `start` should be a no-op on an already running service, so I am not sure what the benefit to this check is.

Comment: when the search that relies on this falls over, i need to stop and start solr.  not just do     systemctl start solr - your comment makes me wonder if it really has gone down or something else is wrong with it and i'm actually turning it off and on again and accidently clearing a problem

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to check that solr is not active then you can do this
`result=$(systemctl is-active solr) if [[ $result != active ]]; then systemctl start solr; fi`